# Datagridview и несколько таблиц

Tags: c#, datagrid, sql

Здраствуйте.

Возникла проблема с написанием выводов результата sql запроса в datagridview. Погулив, я нашел, что datagridview поддерживает работу только с одной таблицей.
Так есть ли возможность составить запрос из 2-х связанных таблиц? Или я просто чего-то не догоняю? Заранее спасибо. :)

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете по идее использовать `DataTable` и [заполнить её результатами запроса](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/24894).

Но лучше не возиться с технологиями позапрошлого века, а освоить Entity Framework или там NHibernate.

Comment: Вы неправы. `DataTable` - это отличный инструмент, незаменимый в тех сценариях, в которых на момент компиляции программы состав колонок неизвестен, и нужно реализовать типовой интерфейс.

Comment: @Modus: У вас не может быть никакой бизнес-логики, если схема базы неизвестна при компиляции. Соответственно ничего полезного, кроме «показать/отредактировать», вы сделать не сможете.

В сколько-нибудь содержательных сценариях Entity Framework сразу даёт преимущество.

Comment: Вы опять неправы. Неизвестная структура данных может, тем не менее, удовлетворять определённым критериям. Я не буду здесь распинаться, лучше мою диссертацию прочитайте: http://www.agrophys.ru/Sergey-Medvedev

Comment: @Modus: 162 страницы мне не осилить, простите.

Разумеется, если есть _какие-то_ данные о схеме, можно построить _какую-то_ бизнес-логику. Чем меньше данных, тем меньше осмысленных операций можно выполнить.

Тем не менее, _типичным_ сценарием является работа программы с одной, _заранее известной_ схемой. (Точно так же как типичным сценарием для объекта является иметь определённый, известный на этапе компиляции тип.)

Answer (score 0):

То, что `DataGridView` поддерживает работу только с одной таблицей, означает, что Вы не сможете с помощью этого компонента сделать древовидную иерархию с шапкой и строками, как, например, при использовании `XtraGrid` от `DevExpress`. `DataGridView` позволяет выводить только двумерную таблицу со строками и столбцами. В первом дотнете был компонент `DataGrid`, который позволял выводить несколько связанных таблиц, там на каждой строчке были плюсики, при нажатии на которые осуществлялся переход к связанной таблице, но это странно и замутно работало, поэтому Microsoft от этого отказались.

Это не имеет никакого отношения к тому, откуда Вы возьмёте данные, чтобы заполнить таблицу. Так что смело делайте сложные запросы и подпихивайте результат их выполнения в `DataGridView`, главное, чтобы этот результат выполнения запроса имел вид одной плоской двумерной таблицы, а не иерархии вложенных списков.